# Create datetime index using a range, impute all NAs by inserting 10 rows per datetime

Tags: python, datetime, rows, nas

I need continuous data in intervals of 1 HR, hence why I wrote this:

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.floor('HR')
dates_range = pd.date_range(df.datetime.min(), df.datetime.max(), freq = 'HR')
df.set_index('datetime', inplace = True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dates_range).set_index(0)
df2 = df.join(df).reset_index()
df2.rename({'index' : 'datetime'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

For missing datetimes, I want to insert 100 rows per HR and fill-in randomly with rows with complete data across from the same dataframe without changing the datetime in the NA rows. How can I do that?

```
    2021-06-10 08:00:00   Shirt        clothes        800
    2021-06-10 08:00:00   Potatoes     food           900
    2021-06-10 08:00:00   Forks        cutlery        700
    ...
    2021-06-10 09:00:00    ''          ''             ''
    ...
    2021-07-23 23:00:00   Fancy Feast  animal food    900
```

Comment: For best results (SO is not a code-writing service), give it a try and let us know where you get stuck!

Comment: Oh, if I post what I've tried you'd have so many pages of code. When I see how I can condense all my code to relevant snip-its, I'll paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (code is not exact but should give an idea):

```
for line in data:
  last_ts = this_ts # save the previous loop's value
  this_ts = datetime.strptime(line[i][:19], date_format)
  while this_ts - last_ts > timedelta(hours=1):
    # copy/print filler/previous line?
    last_ts += timedelta(hours=1)
```